# Automatically import modules when entering the python or ipython interpreter

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I find myself typing `import numpy as np` almost every single time I fire up the python interpreter. How do I set up the python or ipython interpreter so that numpy is automatically imported?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use the environment variable [PYTHONSTARTUP](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP). From the official documentation:

> If this is the name of a readable file, the Python commands in that
>   file are executed before the first prompt is displayed in interactive
>   mode. The file is executed in the same namespace where interactive
>   commands are executed so that objects defined or imported in it can be
>   used without qualification in the interactive session.

So, just create a python script with the import statement and point the environment variable to it. Having said that, remember that 'Explicit is always better than implicit', so don't rely on this behavior for production scripts.

For Ipython, see [this](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html) tutorial on how to make a ipython_config file

Comment: @mklauber, thanks, but the accepted solution there is deprecated. However, it did inspire my edit. @ OP: See my edited answer

Comment: @user545424 as of this writing (ipython 1.1.0) supports PYTHONSTARTUP too.

Comment: Setting `env PYTHONSTARTUP="~/.startup.py"` didn't work for me

Comment: Just a note `export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.python_shell_startup.py` to set the variable.

Answer (score 95):

For ipython, there are two ways to achieve this. Both involve ipython's configuration directory which is located in `~/.ipython`.

1. Create a custom ipython profile.
2. Or you can add a startup file to `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`

For simplicity, I'd use option 2. All you have to do is place a `.py` or `.ipy` file in the `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup` directory and it will automatically be executed. So you could simple place `import numpy as np` in a simple file and you'll have np in the namespace of your ipython prompt.

Option 2 will actually work with a custom profile, but using a custom profile will allow you to change the startup requirements and other configuration based on a particular case. However, if you'd *always* like `np` to be available to you then by all means put it in the startup directory.

For more information on ipython configuration. The [docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files) have a much more complete explanation.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 the directory actually is: `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/startup/` and not `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`

Comment: Unfortunately, option 2 above doesn't allow tab completion.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 the directory actually is: `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/` and not `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/startup/`

Answer (score 28):

I use a ~/.startup.py file like this:

```
# Ned's .startup.py file
print("(.startup.py)")
import datetime, os, pprint, re, sys, time
print("(imported datetime, os, pprint, re, sys, time)")

pp = pprint.pprint
```

Then define PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.startup.py, and Python will use it when starting a shell.

The print statements are there so when I start the shell, I get a reminder that it's in effect, and what has been imported already.  The `pp` shortcut is really handy too...

Comment: Didn't work for me on Linux. Do I have to tell Python to look in my home directory or something?

Comment: oops: forgot an important step: I've added it: define PYTHONSTARTUP

Comment: I never know when the `~` as a substitute for `$HOME` works or not, but instead of this relative path I had to use a absolute path on MacOS, fish and python3.

Comment: [`pprint.pp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pp) now exists, so you might want to change that shortcut to avoid confusion.

Comment: Where should I add the `PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.startup.py`? And shouldn't we use `"` for the path? (`PYTHONSTARTUP="~/.startup.py"`)

Answer (score 8):

While creating a custom startup script like [ravenac95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142531/ravenac95) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124578/automatically-import-modules-when-entering-the-python-or-ipython-interpreter/11124846#11124846) is the best general answer for most cases, it won't work in circumstances where you want to use a `from __future__ import X`. If you sometimes work in Python 2.x but want to use modern division, there is only one way to do this. Once you create a profile, edit the `profile_default` (For Ubuntu this is located in `~/.ipython/profile_default`) and add something like the following to the bottom:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    'from __future__ import division, print_function',
    'import numpy as np',
    'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt',
    ]
```

Answer (score 7):

As a simpler alternative to the accepted answer, on linux:

just define an alias, e.g. put `alias pynp='python -i -c"import numpy as np"'` in your ~/.bash_aliases file. You can then invoke python+numpy with `pynp`, and you can still use just python with `python`. Python scripts' behaviour is left untouched.

Comment: `PYTHONSTARTUP` is only invoked on **interactive** mode, so python scripts‘ behaviour is kept untouched anyways. An alias could also be created with a file reference: `alias pynp='PYTHONSTARTUP="~/.startup.py" python'`

Answer (score 4):

You can create a normal python script as `import_numpy.py` or anything you like

```
#!/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
```

then launch it with `-i` flag.

`python -i import_numpy.py`

Way like this will give you flexibility to choose only modules you want for different projects.

Answer (score 1):

As [ravenac95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142531/ravenac95) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124846/513397), you can either create a custom profile or modify the default profile. This answer is quick view of Linux commands needed to `import numpy as np` automatically.

If you want to use a custom profile called `numpy`, run:

```
ipython profile create numpy
echo 'import numpy as np' >> $(ipython locate profile numpy)/startup/00_imports.py
ipython --profile=numpy
```

Or if you want to modify the default profile to always import numpy:

```
echo 'import numpy as np' >> $(ipython locate profile default)/startup/00_imports.py
ipython
```

Check out the [IPython config tutorial](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/intro.html) to read more in depth about configuring profiles. See `.ipython/profile_default/startup/README` to understand how the startup directory works.

Answer (score 1):

My default `ipython` invocation is

```
ipython --pylab --nosep --InteractiveShellApp.pylab_import_all=False
```

`--pylab` has been a `ipython` option for some time.  It imports `numpy` and (parts of) `matplotlib`.  I've added the `--Inter...` option so it does not use the `*` import, since I prefer to use the explicit `np....`.

This can be a shortcut, alias or script.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little script to get ipython initialized with the code you want.

- Create a `start.ipy` file at your project root folder.
- Edit the created file with all the things you need to get into ipython.
- `ipython profile create <your_profile_name>`. Tip, do not add the word "profile" to the name because ipython already includes it.
- `cp start.ipy ~/.ipython/profile_<your_profile_name>/startup/start.ipy`
- Run `ipython --profile=<your_profile_name>` everytime you need everything loaded in ipython.

With this solution, you don't need to set any env variable up. You will need to copy the `start.ipy` file to the `ipython` folder every time you modify it, though.