# Make IPython Import What I Mean

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I want to modify how IPython handles import errors by default. When I prototype something in the IPython shell, I usually forget to first import `os`, `re` or whatever I need. The first few statements often follow this pattern:

```
In [1]: os.path.exists("~/myfile.txt")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0ffb6014a804> in <module>()
----> 1 os.path.exists("~/myfile.txt")

NameError: name 'os' is not defined

In [2]: import os

In [3]: os.path.exists("~/myfile.txt")
Out[3]: False
```

Sure, that's my fault for having bad habits and,
sure, in a script or real program that makes sense,
but in the shell I'd rather that IPython follow the
DWIM principle, by at least *trying* to import what I am trying to use.

```
In [1]: os.path.exists("~/myfile.txt")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0ffb6014a804> in <module>()
----> 1 os.path.exists("~/myfile.txt")

NameError: name 'os' is not defined

Catching this for you and trying to import "os" … success!
Retrying …
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Out[1]: False
```

If this is not possible with a vanilla IPython, what would I have to do
to make this work? Is a [wrapper kernel](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/development/wrapperkernels.html) the easiest way forward? Or should this be implemented directly in the core, with a magic command?

Note, this is different from [those kind of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124578/automatically-import-modules-when-entering-the-python-or-ipython-interpreter#11124610) where someone wants to always load pre-defined modules. I don't. Cuz I don't know what I will be working on, and I don't want to load *everything* (nor do I want to keep the list of *everything* updated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NOTE:** This is now being maintained [on Github](https://github.com/OrangeFlash81/ipython-auto-import/tree/master). Download the latest version of the script from there!

I developed a script that binds to IPython's exception handling through `set_custom_exc`. If there's a `NameError`, it uses a regex to find what module you tried to use and then attempt to import it. It then runs the function you tried to call again. Here is the code:

```
import sys, IPython, colorama # <-- colorama must be "pip install"-ed

colorama.init()

def custom_exc(shell, etype, evalue, tb, tb_offset=None):
    pre = colorama.Fore.CYAN + colorama.Style.BRIGHT + "AutoImport: " + colorama.Style.NORMAL + colorama.Fore.WHITE
    if etype == NameError:
        shell.showtraceback((etype, evalue, tb), tb_offset) # Show the normal traceback
        import re
        try:
            # Get the name of the module you tried to import
            results = re.match("name '(.*)' is not defined", str(evalue))
            name = results.group(1)

            try:
                __import__(name)
            except:
                print(pre + "{} isn't a module".format(name))
                return

            # Import the module
            IPython.get_ipython().run_code("import {}".format(name))
            print(pre + "Imported referenced module \"{}\", will retry".format(name))
        except Exception as e:
            print(pre + "Attempted to import \"{}\" but an exception occured".format(name))

        try:
            # Run the failed line again
            res = IPython.get_ipython().run_cell(list(get_ipython().history_manager.get_range())[-1][-1])
        except Exception as e:
            print(pre + "Another exception occured while retrying")
            shell.showtraceback((type(e), e, None), None)
    else:
        shell.showtraceback((etype, evalue, tb), tb_offset=tb_offset)

# Bind the function we created to IPython's exception handler
IPython.get_ipython().set_custom_exc((Exception,), custom_exc)
```

You can make this run automatically when you start an IPython prompt by saving it somewhere and then setting an environment variable called `PYTHONSTARTUP` to the path to this file. You set environment variables differently depending on your OS (remember to alter the paths):

- Windows: `setx PYTHONSTARTUP C:\startup.py` in command prompt
- Mac/Linux (bash): Put `export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/startup.py` into your `~/.bashrc`

Here's a demo of the script in action:

[image: Demo]

Comment: _Currently, this script infinite-loops on some errors_ - if import results in NameError and clean-up routine does same import... - you already know what happens. You need to check if module you're trying to import exists.

Comment: @Rogalski How would I do that? I know `pip` has methods to do this but somebody might be importing something that's on their local machine.

Comment: Run: `try: import whatever except ImportError: oops_failed_to_import_handle_it()`?

Comment: @Rogalski Thanks, I'm updating it to support this, as well as have clearer output.

Comment: @Rogalski This has now been updated to look prettier and not infinite loop.

Comment: Nice, a IPython exception handler seems appropriate! Why did you just pass `NameError` as [first parameter for set_custom_exc](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html?highlight=set_custom_exc#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.set_custom_exc)? Finally, would there be a way to distinguish `NameError`s that occur in the *library or program code* from the ones in the shell? If my program code has a bug, resulting in such a NameError, then trying to import the variable name will only make things worse.

Comment: @mknecht Oh, I'll look into `set_custom_exc`'s parameters. I don't think there's a way of detecting where an error came from, but I'll look into it.

Comment: I think, we'd have to do some stack trace analysis or so … anyway, your answer is the way forward I think.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 would you consider putting your code snippet under a permissive license such as BSD or MIT or so? Would love to see this finished up, and made usable for more people. (pip installable or so)

Comment: @mknecht Sure! Later I'll make a Github repo under the MIT license and post it here.