# Launch Jupyter Notebook with launcher and basic code in Linux Mint

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, linux-mint

I currently open Jupyter Notebook by running `jupyter notebook` in my terminal.

I have 2 questions that relate to a common goal.

1) How do I create a desktop icon (i.e. launcher) to start Jupyter Notebook on my Linux Mint computer?

2) I want to run some basic code upon double-clicking this launcher:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import sklearn as skl
```

I don't want to type this code whenever I open Jupyter Notebook, so it would be nice to automatically run it.

For #1, I'm trying to follow the steps here:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=256156#p1382045

However, I don't know where to find the path for the "Command" field. I tried browsing the Anaconda folder on my computer, but I can't find Jupyter Notebook there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Although I asked two questions, they actually are necessary compliments toward a common, unified goal. I broke it down into two questions to make it clear. I think that I actually made my overall request easier to answer as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For your first question,** if you open up a terminal, you can find where programs are with `which`, like so

```
which jupyter
```

This should output where your particular `jupyter` is being called from.

**For your second question,** it looks like you can create a profile to start up certain functions.

In bash, you can run the following

```
# Create a new folder if it already doesn't exist
mkdir -p ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup

# Create Python file to put your favorite imports
touch ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/start.py
```

So the `start.py` (that is located in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`) is where you can put your imports. So this `start.py` file should contain

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import sklearn as skl
```

Resources:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-automatically-import-your-favorite-libraries-into-ipython-or-a-jupyter-notebook-9c69d89aa343
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124846/
- https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files

**In sum,** if you implement *both* of the suggestions above, you can get both an icon to auto-load your favorite Python library packages as you start a Jupyter Notebook.

**Warning:** typically for reproducibility and transferability of Jupyter Notebooks to others, I would go against auto-loading libraries into your Jupyter Notebook. I understand the repetition of having to load the same libraries you use all the time, but if for whatever reason, you change computers or a colleague needs your code, then your notebook will not work correctly. Just my two cents to keep in mind if/when implementing this.