# Python 3.6 save function inside the shell

Tags: python

I have a question, is it possible to save a created function like shown in the picture "Created function inside the shell" to the shell itself, so that I can call this function even after I closed the shell and re-opened it ?

[image: Created function inside the shell]

Comment: You should write python code in a `.py` file.

Comment: you can write packages, and the packages can later be imported and called like ```import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.now())```

Comment: this might help you, you can create a file with your function, and that file will be run every time you open the python shell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124578/automatically-import-modules-when-entering-the-python-or-ipython-interpreter

Comment: In IPython, you can use profiles and save the code into e.g. `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup`. It will run in the beginning of each shell session.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the code in python file and save the code.

```
def hello_print():
   print("Hello")
```

Save above  code in python file i.e., *hello_world.py*

And then run the file using following command in CMD:

```
python hello_world.py
```

later if you want to use the function in another code then you can import the function as follows:

```
from hello_world import hello_world
```