# Overwriting the builtin Python Print

Tags: python, rich

Nowadays I pretty much only using the Python Rich implementation for printing. i.e `from rich import print`.

Rather than adding this to every script I write, is there a way to replace the built-in Python print with the Rich implementation?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11124578/3001761?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a script [`usercustomize.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#the-customization-modules) inside the user site-packages directory which performs the import and assigns it to the `builtins`:

```
import builtins
import rich

builtins.print = rich.print
```

Also check the documentation of the [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) for more information (the same can be achieved for all users via `sitecustomize.py`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [~/.pythonrc.py](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#the-interactive-startup-file) for your local repl.

```
# ~/.pythonrc.py
from rich import print
```